# Преобразование многомерных структур в одномерные

Tags: rust

Можно ли используя `.iter()` `.into_iter()` `.map()` ну и `.rev()` получить `Vec<i32>` равный `[6,5,4,3,2,1]` из каждой переменной `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, `x5`? Или без `for` никак? Если же можно, покажите, пожалуйста, как.

```
fn main() {

  let x1 = vec![vec![1,2],vec![3,4],vec![5,6]];
  let x2 = vec![[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
  let x3 = [vec![1,2],vec![3,4],vec![5,6]];
  let x4 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
  let x5 = [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]],[[5],[6]]];

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, переформулируйте вопрос более понятно что из чего вы хотите получить и как

Comment: Вопрос вполне должен быть понятен. Есть многомерные структуры `x1 ... x5`. Нужно получить вектор `[6,5,4,3,2,1]` для каждого `xn`. Не используя цикл `for`

Comment: Что такое x1 ... x5 не понятно

Comment: `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, `x5` - это переменные, которые нужно обработать и получить `[6,5,4,3,2,1]` для каждой. Ну в коде же это есть!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используя только перечисленные функции - нельзя. Можно с использованием `flat_map`

```
fn main() {
    let x1 = vec![vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4], vec![5, 6]];
    let x2 = vec![[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];
    let x3 = [vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4], vec![5, 6]];
    let x4 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];
    let x5 = [[[1], [2]], [[3], [4]], [[5], [6]]];
    let y: Vec<_> = x1.iter().rev().flat_map(|v| v.iter().rev()).cloned().collect();
    println!("{:?}", y);
    let y: Vec<_> = x2.iter().rev().flat_map(|v| v.iter().rev()).cloned().collect();
    println!("{:?}", y);
    let y: Vec<_> = x3.iter().rev().flat_map(|v| v.iter().rev()).cloned().collect();
    println!("{:?}", y);
    let y: Vec<_> = x4.iter().rev().flat_map(|v| v.iter().rev()).cloned().collect();
    println!("{:?}", y);
    let y: Vec<_> = x5.iter().rev().flat_map(|v| v.iter().rev().flat_map(|v| v.iter().rev())).cloned().collect();
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=75b7b2c0222df0489bfa6e45c87a3a7a&version=stable&mode=debug)

Comment: Если есть возможность использовать unstable фичи, можно вместо flat_map использовать [flatten](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten), тогда последний пример сократится до `x5.iter().flatten().flatten().cloned().collect()` .

Comment: red75prim, супер, то что надо!

Comment: Flowneee, спасибо!